# Adding duplicate core data strings to an email

Tags: ios, xcode, string, email

*I have a few core data strings that i want to add to an email so when the user clicks the email button, the multiple strings are pulled. I just dont know how to add more than one.*

**heres the string- (self.personquantityTextField.text) I want to add (self.personroom5TextField.text) to email body.**

```
NSString *emailBody = self.personquantityTextField.text;

[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES]; // depends. Mostly YES, unless you want to send it as plain text (boring)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine two NSString like this.

```
NSString *combinedStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", self.personquantityTextField.text, self.personroom5TextField.text];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableString *body = [NSMutableString new];
[body appendString:self.someTextField.text];
[body appendString:self.someOtherTextField.text];
[body appendString:self.someThirdTextField.text];

[picker setMessageBody:body isHTML:YES];
```